# Failing test in Angular

Tags: angular, testing, promise, rxjs

I was following a video, where it talks about async testing, and I made the same code, with some differences because of Angular versions (the video is 2 years old). However, I am having a problem with asyncrounious testing.

> Expected undefined to equal 'testTtess'

```
import { TtessComponent } from './ttess.component'
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, tick, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TtessService } from './ttes.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

describe('TtesComponent', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TtessComponent>;
  let component: TtessComponent;
  let ttessService: TtessService;
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [TtessComponent]
  });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TtessComponent);
  component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  ttessService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TtessService);
});

it('should creat component instance', () => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});


it(`it should render h1 tag with title 'My car header'`, () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const nativeEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  expect(nativeEl.querySelector('h1').textContent).toEqual('My car header')
})

it('should inject Ttess service', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.isCarVisible).toEqual(ttessService.getVisibility());
})


it('should display car if is not visible', () => {
  ttessService.showTtess();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const nativeEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  expect(nativeEl.querySelector('span').textContent).toEqual('Car is visible');

})

it(`shouldn't get car name if not async`, () => {
  spyOn(ttessService, 'getTtessName')
  .and.returnValue(of('testTtess')
  .pipe(delay(100)));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.ttessName).toBe(undefined);
})

it(`should get car name if async`, async(() => {
  spyOn(ttessService, 'getTtessName').and.returnValue(of('testTtess').pipe(delay(100)));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.ttessName).toEqual('testTtess');
  });

}));

});


\===========Service===============\

export class TtessService {
    private IsCarVisible: boolean = true;

    showTtess() {
        this.IsCarVisible = true;
    }
    hideIttess() {
        this.IsCarVisible = false;
    }

    getVisibility() {
        return this.IsCarVisible;
    }

    getTtessName(): Observable<string> {
        return of('Ford').pipe(delay(100));
    }
}

\===============Component=================\
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TtessService } from './ttes.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ttess',
  templateUrl: './ttess.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ttess.component.scss'],
  providers: [TtessService]
})
export class TtessComponent implements OnInit {
  isCarVisible:boolean;
title = 'My car header';
ttessName: string;
  constructor(private ttess: TtessService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isCarVisible = this.ttess.getVisibility();
    this.ttess.getTtessName()
    .subscribe(name => this.ttessName);
  }

}
```

Comment: that's the video which i was watching

Answer (score 1):

Try it with

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isCarVisible = this.ttess.getVisibility();
    this.ttess.getTtessName()
    .subscribe(name => this.ttessName = name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your components? If you use the cli to create your components the you get a boilerplate test spec with them.

```
ng g c Ttess
```

Will create the shell for the component, template css and spec files and add the component to your module.

Then you will see that latest spec boilerplate already are async in the before each and the component is ready to test.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TtessComponent } from './ttess.component';

describe('TtessComponent', () => {
  let component: TtessComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TtessComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AcfiHeadingComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TtessComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: yeah I know, but in that case I'v used the example for learning